# Halfing a string at a particular character

Tags: java

So, I have a string called `prox`y, it has the value of `194.156.123.1.1:8080`.

How do I halve it at the colon?

So I want 2 variables like this.

```
IP=194.156.123.1.1
PORT=8080
```

I know this is really easy, but I'm new, and new people have problems that may seem easier to the experienced :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried having a look at Substring, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Use [string.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String proxy = "194.156.123.1.1:8080";
String[] foo = string.split(":");
String ip = foo[0]; // 194.156.123.1.1
String port = foo[1]; // 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done Using split method on string class

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String proxy = "194.156.123.1.1:8080";
String[] op = proxy.split(":"); //op[0] = "194.156.123.1.1" and
                                //op[1] = "8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "194.156.123.1.1:8080";
    String ip = s.split(":")[0];
    String port = s.split(":")[1];

    System.out.println(ip + ", " + port);
```

Split should segregate the string into string array.

Here's from the Java Doc:

public String[] split(String regex)
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

Regex   Result
:   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
Parameters:
regex - the delimiting regular expression

Returns:
the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
$len = strlen($str);
$pos = strpose($str, ':');    

if ($pos>0 && $pos <($len-1)) {

    $ip = substr($str, 0, $pos);
    $port = substr($str, $pos+1);

}
```

substr and strpos are more efficient and faster.

I have added the bound check,then it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
    String proxy= "194.156.123.1.1:8080";
    System.out.println("IP: "+proxy.split(":")[0]);
    System.out.println("PORT: "+proxy.split(":")[1]);
```